# Sides of laptop display have turned black causing just the middle of the screen to be visible

Tags: laptop-repair

I have had this Windows 8.1 laptop for a couple of years now.  Just 2 days ago both sides of the screen went black and the problem will not go away.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What?  It isn't clear to me what your problem is.  Can you attach a picture?

Comment: Whilst waiting for the picture; have you changed the screen resolution or plugged an external monitor into the side of the laptop? If you've changed the resolution then change it to something else (higher) to see if the black lines disappear. If you've got a monitor plugged in, disconnect it to see if the screen goes back to normal...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happened on my HP8510P Laptop.
I'd changed the display settings, accidentally setting it darker then it should have been when the cord was plugged in. After starting the laptop with just the battery, I went into the display settings and made both battery & power Line as bright as possible., then I shutdown the laptop, inserted the power cord & rebooted - this time all was well.
Fixed my problem - will leave display settings alone from now on.